# Problem Adding Navigation Controller to MainWindow Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I'm sure this is something obvious, but how do I add a nav controller to the main window in xcode 4 - when I drag and drop it won't let me drop the nav controller on the window.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left of the IB view, you have an object panel. Expand it (the little arrow at the bottom) and you will see the xib components. Drag and drop your controller into this area.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder - Window - YourFileName.xib(the last option)
It makes the window active
Then drag and drop the controller to the list of files(where you can see "File's owner").